# Squid3 HTTPS connections seem slow

Tags: squid

We have a strange issue using squid 3.1.19 on an ubuntu box. HTTPS connections seem to be very slow, and i've no idea why. They sometimes do eventually work, but most of the time just time out. If I don't go through the proxy they are fine.

I know squid doesn't cache https for obvious reasons, so i'm not sure why it should be slow. We are using active directory auth if that makes any difference.

Comment: Anything in the logs? Time outs, errors, warnings?

Comment: No, i can see the requests coming in, the only odd thing is some of the requests have'nt got a user name against them so they are getting denied, but some have and they are accepted